# Does Review Board support commenting on individual lines in an attached source file?

Tags: review-board

I downloaded and installed [Review Board](http://www.reviewboard.org/) in order to evaluate its fit for our team's workflow.  I see that you can attach files to a review.  When I go to review an attached file, Review Board lets me add a comment to the entire file, but I don't see a way to comment on individual lines within the file.

***How can I comment on individual lines in an attached source file?***

Comment: Can you provide a link to Review Board?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.7/) for the current version (more specifically, see [Creating Review Requests](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.7/users/review-requests/creating/) and [Reviewing File Attachments](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.7/users/reviews/reviewing-files/) page), it is only possible to comment on non-diff files **as a whole**. I have tried to find a workaround, but I have not been successful.

[This wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/reviewboard/wiki/IdeasFor2_0), which contains ideas for the 2.0 version, says the following:

> There has been some request for reviewing files other than diffs.
>   Screenshots have been the main one, though someone suggested Wiki
>   changes and specialized views for certain text documents.

So maybe this will be possible in 2.0, but as of 1.7, **it is not possible**.